# How do I update SQL Server from a DataTable?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am reading a subset of a table into a DataTable and modifying the DataTable.  I need to update the original SQL Server table with the updated information.

Ultimately I took Mark Kram's suggestion and used SqlBulkCopy to put the DataTable data into an SQL Server table, then ran an SQL UPDATE statement to update the weekly data.

```vb
Dim conn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = ConnString}
dim strSQL as String, Sum13 as Double, x as Int16, y as Int16
strSQL = "SELECT Symbol, WeekEnd, AdjClose, Avg13, StdDev13 FROM Weekly " &
    "WHERE Symbol = '" & strSym & "' ORDER BY WeekEnd DESC;"
Dim sdCmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
Dim sdda As New SqlDataAdapter(sdCmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable
sdda.Fill(dt)
conn.Open()

'calculate the 13 week moving average
Dim row As DataRow
For x = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 13
    Sum13 = 0
    For y = x To x + 12
        Sum13 += dt.Rows(y).Item("AdjClose")
    Next
    dt.Rows(x).Item("Avg13") = Math.Round(Sum13 / 13, 4)
Next

'calculate the 13 week standard deviation
For x = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 13
    Sum13 = 0
    For y = x To x + 12
        Sum13 += (dt.Rows(y).Item("AdjClose") - dt.Rows(x).Item("Avg13")) ^ 2
    Next
    dt.Rows(x).Item("StdDev13") = Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(Sum13 / 12), 4)
Next
```

The final piece was to insert the data into a temporary table, then update the Weekly SQL Server table.  I created the "TempWeekly" table to match the DataTable and just reuse it.

```vb
'load the TempDaily table with the DataTable
strSQL = "DELETE FROM TempWeekly"
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(conn)
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TempWeekly"
    Dim mapSym As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Symbol", "Symbol")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapSym)
    Dim mapWeekEnd As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("WeekEnd", "WeekEnd")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapWeekEnd)
    Dim mapStdDev13 As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("StdDev13", "StdDev13")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapStdDev13)
    Dim mapAvg13 As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Avg13", "Avg13")
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapAvg13)
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)
End Using

'update the Weekly table from TempDaily
strSQL = "UPDATE Weekly " &
    "SET Weekly.Avg13 = TempWeekly.Avg13, " &
        "Weekly.StdDev13 = TempWeekly.StdDev13 " &
    "FROM TempWeekly " &
    "WHERE (Weekly.Symbol = TempWeekly.Symbol) AND " & 
        (Weekly.WeekEnd = TempWeekly.WeekEnd) AND " &
        (TempWeekly.Avg13 <> 0);"
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: If it were me I would Bulk Insert the data into a SQL server temp table and take care of the DML stuff in SQL server.

Comment: You can use SQLCommandBuider for this https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You just need to set the `UpdateCommand` of your data adapter and then call `Update` to save the changes.  You can, as suggested, use a command builder to generate the required command if there will be nothing fancy in your SQL.  [Examples here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872).

Comment: It looks like you're using a fire hose to put out a match stick. You could have accomplished this with 3 lines of code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I can't use CommandBuilder because neither (dt or dbo.Weekly) have a primary key.  At least that's my understanding from both MS Visual Studio Docs and your post on VB Forums.

Comment: So don't use a command builder then.  Did you follow the link I provided?  It has an example with and one without.  That said, you will need to be able to uniquely identify each record if you want to be able to update them so, if you have no primary key, you'd better have some other means.